Easy guideline for using JPL Horizons DE431 for planets in aphelion and perihelion from 11000 BC to 16000 AD?
Can someone give me a step by step Guide how to use JPL DE431 or DE441 as a Beginner.
I tried the Horizons website app and Webgeocalc but it didn't showed understandable Information.
This websites forum and others were searched.
It would be enough when I'm able to read one example like:
Julian Day Number________Date__________Planet_________Position
-652942.5000000_____-6500-05-05_______Venus________aphelion
This would be very helpful.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Futur AE, you might want to write up the results of the discussion as a self-answer, to help folks who have similar problems in the future.

Have you explored Skyfield library ? I used it to find solar eclipses at a particular location from 5000 BC to 2000 AD. Here is the code for your reference.
https://github.com/godbolerr/indianskyfield/blob/master/iastronomy/KuruSolarEclipseBC.py
